# Some doubts regarding projective scheme with an ample line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over a field $k$, and let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $X$.

1. Is it true that $X\simeq \text{Proj}(\bigoplus_{n\geq 0} H^0(X,L^n))?$
2. If $L$ is very ample (which we can always assume by substituting $L$ with a large power of $L$), there is a natural map $\text{Sym}(H^0(X,L))\rightarrow \bigoplus_{n\geq 0}H^0(X,L^n)$. Does this give the required closed embedding of $X$ into some projective space?

I could not find these in Hartshorne. Any reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No, because $\mathcal{O}_X$ is not pulling back $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\operatorname{Proj}\bigoplus H^0(X,L^n)$.

Comment: @user10354138 do you mean in question 1 or 2?  Isn't pullback of trivial bundle always trivial? Sorry for my lack of knowledge. Some explanation would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I seem to have found my answer. Let me write it down for for future reference. I would be very grateful if someone goes through the argument and tell me if it's ok or not.

1. In the book *Ulrich Gortz, Torsten Wedhorn - Algebraic Geometry I - Schemes with examples and exercises*, Proposition 13.48, the authors prove the following:

> Let $X$ be a quasi-compact and quasi-separated scheme, let $L$ be an ample invertible sheaf on $X$. Then there exists a quasi-compact schematically dominant open immersion $r: X\rightarrow \text{Proj}(\bigoplus_{n\geq 0} H^0(X, L^n)).$

(They construct the immersion $r$ just before stating the proposition.)

Moreover, since we have assumed $X$ is projective, it is proper over $k$. Then it follows from [Corollary 13.41 of the same reference above] that $r$ is a proper morphism. Hence $r(X)$ is closed. A dense open immersion which has closed image must be an isomorphism.

(Edit: this result is explicitly mentioned in Corollary 13.75).

2. This is an application of Serre's vanishing theorem. Let us first prove the following.

> *Claim* : $\exists n_0\geq 0$ such that the natural map $H^0(X,L)^{\otimes n}\rightarrow H^0(X,L^n)$ is surjective $\forall\,n\geq n_0.$

*Proof* : Since $L$ is very ample, let $\iota: X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^r_k$ be the closed immersion so that $\iota^*(\mathcal{O}(1))\simeq L$. Let $\mathscr{I}$ denote the ideal sheaf of $X$. By Serre's vanishing theorem, there exists $n_0\geq 0$ such that $H^1(\mathbb{P}^r,\mathscr{I}(n))=0\,\forall\,n\geq n_0$. The exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathscr{I}(n)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(n)\rightarrow \iota_*\mathcal{O}_X(n)\rightarrow 0$
then gives us $H^0(\mathbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}(n))\twoheadrightarrow H^0(X, L^n)\,\forall\,n\geq n_0.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(*)$

The composition $H^0(\mathbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}(1))^{\otimes n}\twoheadrightarrow H^0(\mathbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}(n))\twoheadrightarrow H^0(X, L^n)$ clearly factors through $H^0(X,L)^{\otimes n}\rightarrow H^0(X,L^n)$, thus the latter map must be surjective as well. *QED*

Replacing $L$ by $L^{n_0}$, we get

> $H^0(X,L)^{\otimes n}\twoheadrightarrow H^0(X, L^n)\,\forall\,n\geq 1.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(*)$

Let $A:= \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} H^0(X, L^n).$ The above claim shows that $A$ is a finitely generated commutative graded $k$-algebra generated by $A_1$. By (1), we already know that $X\simeq \text{Proj}(A)$. Now, by the above claim there exists a surjection $B:=\text{Sym}(H^0(X,L))\twoheadrightarrow A$, which produces a closed immersion $j: \text{Proj}(A)\hookrightarrow \text{Proj}(B)=\mathbb{P}(H^0(X,L)^{\vee})\simeq \mathbb{P}^r$ for some $r$. Define $\iota := j\circ r$. Now, $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(1)= B(1)^{\sim}$, and $\iota^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(1))= r^*((A\otimes_B B(1))^{\sim}) \simeq r^*(A(1)^{\sim})$. We claim that $r^*(A(1)^{\sim}) \simeq L$.

Replacing $L$ by a larger power if necessary, by [Gortz-Wedhorn, Proposition 13.47 (iv)], there exists finitely many $f_i\in H^0(X,L)$ such that $X_{f_i}$ is affine for all $i$ and they cover $X$. Since $r$ is an isomorphism and $r^{-1}(D_+(f_i))=X_{f_i}$ (see the construction of $r$ in page 388 Gortz-Wedhorn), we get that $D_+(f_i)$'s cover $\text{Proj}A$ as well. Since $f_i$'s live in degree 1, $A(1)^{\sim}|_{D_+(f_i)}=(A_{(f_i)}\cdot f_i)^{\sim}$, and hence $r^*(A(1)^{\sim}|_{D_+(f_i)})= (\mathcal{O}(X_{f_i})\otimes_{A_{(f_i)}}A_{(f_i)}\cdot f_i)^{\sim} = (\mathcal{O}(X_{f_i})\cdot f_i)^{\sim}$. Since multiplying by $f_i$ gives an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{X_{f_i}}\simeq L|_{X_{f_i}}$ and $X_{f_i}$ is affine, we conclude that $(\mathcal{O}(X_{f_i})\cdot f_i)^{\sim}= L|_{X_{f_i}}$. Thus $r^*(A(1)^{\sim}) \simeq L$.